# Why do we add 6 in BCD addition?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary

When performing addition in BCD, if we get an invalid BCD value, we remedy this by adding 6 to our sum.

For example:

$0101 + 0110 = 1011$ (Invalid in BCD)

So, we add 6 to fix this.

$1011 + 0110 = 0001 0001$

I've been told that it is to skip the 6 invalid BCD stages, but I have a problem with this. But, if our result was 14 we would only need to skip 1 invalid BCD combination So, why do we need to add 6 specifically?

Comment: So we add 6 because it guarantees that you have to add a new digit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$10_{bcd}=0001\ 0000_b=16_d$$
$$11_{bcd}=0001\ 0001_b=17_d$$
$$12_{bcd}=0001\ 0010_b=18_d$$
$$13_{bcd}=0001\ 0011_b=19_d$$
$$14_{bcd}=0001\ 0100_b=20_d$$
$$...$$
As you see, the discrepancy is always $6$. A carry from a BCD digit to the next converts ten units to a single tenth, but a BCD tenth has weight $16$ instead of $10_d$, hence the correction $6$.

Answer (score 0):

Because each hexadecimal digit has 16 different values and BCD has only 10. When you do math in decimal, if a number is larger than 10 you need to take the modulus of 10 and carry to the next row. Similarly, in BCD math, when the result of the addition is larger than 9 you add 6 to skip the 6 remaining "invalid" values and carry to the next digit. Conversely you'll need to subtract 6 in subtractions.

For example: 27 + 36

```
  27: 0010 0111
+ 36: 0011 0110
───────────────
5_13: 0101 1101 (13 >= 10)
+  6:      0110
───────────────
  63: 0110 0011 (13 + 6 = 19 = 0x13 which 0x3 is the units digit and 0x10 is the carry)
```

For more information you can read [Why must six be added to a BCD addition if it is an invalid BCD code?](https://www.quora.com/Why-must-six-be-added-to-a-BCD-addition-if-it-is-an-invalid-BCD-code)

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you add 2 numbers (0-9), if the sum>=10, the required bcd should be: 
0001, followed by 4 bits representing the last decimal digit.

Eg:-
8+8=16
1000+1000= 10000, but required BCD: 0001 0110

To obtain the binary representation of the last digit, you need to subtract ten
(i.e, 1010)

This is the same thing as adding the 2’s complement of 1010 which is, 0110( 6 )

In binary subtraction of unsigned numbers using 2’s complement method, you will always have an end carry when the result is positive.

Continuing the previous example,

10000

+0110

Ans:  1(end carry) 0110

Upon adding leading zeroes:

0001 0110, which is the required BCD